# Evaluate $ \int_{-2}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{\left ( 1-x \right )\left ( x+2 \right )^2}{x+3}}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate the integral:
$$\int_{-2}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{\left ( 1-x \right )\left ( x+2 \right )^2}{x+3}}\,dx$$

but I have no clue of how to start in order to attack it.

I cannot even split that root because it does not make sense otherwise.
Any hints on how to begin?

**Edit:** Typos were corrected...

Comment: You should change your title!

Comment: Thank you.. title changed... and still I have not made any progess on the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Notice that
$$\int_{-2}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{\left ( 1-x \right )\left ( x+2 \right )^2}{x+3}}\,dx = \int_{-2}^{1} (x+2)\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x+3}}\,dx, \text{because $ x\geq -2$}.$$

Take $t^2 = \frac{1-x}{x+3} \implies x= \frac{1-3t^2}{t^2+1}\implies dx = \frac{-8t}{(t^2+1)^2}\,dt.$

Hence,

$$\int_{-2}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{\left ( 1-x \right )\left ( x+2 \right )^2}{x+3}}\,dx = 8\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{(3-t^2)t^2}{(t^2+1)^3}\,dt.$$

Now, let $f(t) = t^3$ and $g(t) = (t^2+1)^2$. Notice that
$$\frac{(3-t^2)t^2}{(t^2+1)^3} = \frac{f'(t)g(t) - f(t)g'(t)}{g(t)^2}.$$

I think you can finish now!

Comment: Hey... this looks promising.. let's see if I can finish the last using only high school methods... (since these kind of methods are requiered from the book for this one)

Comment: @Tolaso if you want calculate $\int_0^\sqrt{3}\dfrac{(3-t^2)t^2}{(t^2+1)^3}\,dt$ I think you must know partial fraction decomposition of rational fractions

Comment: @Tolaso, I have added more details.

Comment: @Scientifica Yep.. I do.. !

Comment: @AlexSilva Thank you...

Comment: @Tolaso, You are welcome!! :)